# Is there a Cramer's conjecture for Sophie Germain primes?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, probabilistic-number-theory, prime-gaps

A prime $q$ such that $2q+1$ is also a prime is a Sophie Germain prime.

Cramer's conjecture tells gap between consecutive primes is bound by $O(\log^2p)$.

Is there a similar conjecture for Sophie Germain primes?

Comment: @FedorPetrov Could you make it as an answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Heuristics says that $n$ is Sophie Germain prime with probability roughly $1/\log^2n$. Thus the probability that $C\log^an$×consecutive numbers starting from $n$×are not Sophie Germain primes is about $(1−1/\log^2n)^{C\log^an} \sim e^{−C\log^{a−2} n}$ which is too large when $a<3$ and equals $n^{-C} $ when $a=3$. So, it is natural to predict $O(\log^3p)$ bound.

Comment: Is there an expected prime number theorem for these Sophie Germain primes? Is it just $\frac{n}{\log^2n}$?

Comment: @Turbo with some constant, I guess it should be $2 \prod_p (1-2/p)/(1-1/p)^2$, the product is over odd primes. Maybe it is too naive, though.

Comment: is there a closed form or anything close to it?